# what does "additional logging output above" mean in npm?

Tags: json, css, npm, sass, npm-scripts

> "This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above".

What does this mean and how can I resolve this error?

It also shows the following:

> npm ERR! code ELIECYCLE
>   npm ERR! errno 1

Answer (score 0):

It means that npm recognizes that a problem occurred and there should usually be a lot of logging output before this line in your console.

above means „vertically above“ on the screen.

What causes this?

I‘d reckon:

You did something wrong in your code presumably in the HTML-part and the compiler now throws an error.

Comment: I was using autoprefixer for css,        "prefix:css": "postcss --use autoprefixer -b 'last 10 versions' css/style.concat.css -o css/style.prefix.css"